# Get type inference from keys in a dynamic array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am looking to get type inference based on the value of keys in an array.

For context, I'm working on a class where you can pass in a list of options and a default value:

```
interface Option {
    value: string;
}

interface SelectArgs {
    options: Option[];
    defaultValue: Option['value'];
}

class SelectConfig {
    options: Option[];
    defaultValue: Option['value'] // can I get the value options with autocompletion here?

    constructor(args: SelectArgs ) {
        Object.assign(this, args);
    }

}
```

I would be using this in the context of a class, so for example, if I instantiate a new class:

```
const select = new SelectOptions({
    options: [{value: 'Hello'}, {value: 'World'}]
    defaultValue: "Hello" // I want to give me type inference of either "Hello" | "World"

})
```

What is the best way to type `defaultValue` in this case so it is always one of the passed in `values` of `options`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it'll look something like this, using a generic parameter for the class:

```
type Narrow<T> =
    | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
    | Extract<T, number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []>
    | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });

class SelectConfig<Options extends Option[]> {
    options!: Options;
    defaultValue!: Options[number]['value'] 

    constructor(args: {
        options: Narrow<Options>;
        defaultValue: Options[number]["value"]
    }) {
        Object.assign(this, args);
    }
}
```

I opted to use this `Narrow` utility type so you don't need to use `as const` when creating the class. We'll narrow the type of the given options, then set the type of the default value to any of the values given in the options.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wzeb1m)

Comment: The instance members should be using the generic `Options` here, not `Option`.

Comment: Nice catch, for some reason I was concerned that later on when you used the members it would give you type errors because the members were too specific (adding options, etc), but it looks like it doesn't.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know yet about this Narrow utility. Where did you find it?

Comment: @ViktorLuft I found it in the TypeScript community Discord server. It's very commonly used, so much so that their Discord bot has a command to bring this type up.

Comment: Also, `as const` is probably fine, and arguably a lot simpler. Regardless, nice answer, up voted!

Comment: Well I suppose, but I hate typing those 8 extra characters. It just makes me feel my code is a little dirty 